# Weather Head Re-attachment

Tags: electrical, code-compliance, inspection

Live in Sandy Springs, GA. Just bought an older home and electrical is not up to current code. I had a big branch fall on overhead service line and pull weather head out from attic. Power is still on and there are no issues, but it is just detached. I need to get it re-attached (nothing added or removed), so they'll need to turn power off to do so. I'm worried that after the repair is done, they'll need an inspection and notice that my electrical isn't up to code, keeping them from turning the power back on. I've talked to multiple electricians and the power company and have gotten mixed reviews, so thought I'd ask here.

Does anyone know if this is the case, or should I be fine with having a service cut, have it fixed, then simply turn it back on. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Most likely, they'll just inspect the mast. However, to be sure, ask your local inspector. If he says he's going to inspect the whole house, at least you'll know. I would consider this unlikely, though.

Answer (score 3):

The *general* rule is that if things were done properly to code *at the time of installation* then repair work does not require bringing things up to current code. Depending on jurisdiction, that can even go as far as replacing a panel not requiring adding AFCI and GFCI to circuits, even though those circuit breakers are going to be all new.

That being said, jurisdictions, and in some cases particular inspectors, may see things differently. In addition, if it turns out something was not done right in the first place then everything is fair game.